# I get NULL retrieving JSON from especific website

Tags: php, json

I want to retrieve the JSON data from [here](https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&format=plain&anonymous=true&address=12Za1i1zhYTCeHWBg8yJb72BeEGQVEuMdT&callback=http://example.com):

```
{

    "input_address": "1BeE32K9FxvrnBNeuKwdyM26vZ4GsggqZG",
    "callback_url": "http://example.com",
    "fee_percent": 1.5,
    "destination": "12Za1i1zhYTCeHWBg8yJb72BeEGQVEuMdT"

}
```

... If you put that on your browser you'll see that the JSON data is correctly formatted. No problem there.

However, when I try to retrieve the data with PHP using the standard script:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&format=plain&anonymous=true&address=12Za1i1zhYTCeHWBg8yJb72BeEGQVEuMdT&callback=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($JSON);
var_dump($data);
echo 'url: '.$url;
?>
```

... I get no data; the var_dump writes "NULL" (you can test the previous code at http://bitstamina.com/theamazinghat/thehat.php). And yet, if I try any other url that returns JSON data my code works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? It must be either a very stupid mistake on my part, or that the site blockchain.info has blocked my site from making requests.

Comment: output `json_last_error()`

Comment: I just tested your code and its working fine.Please try again. I have tested using cli.

Comment: You should first `var_dump()` the `$JSON` variable. Whatever, your code works for me as is.

Comment: Perhaps use urlencode() - you've got some special characters there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to a cross domain mismatch.  Changing your page to https or call using http. 
    http://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&format=plain&anonymous=true&address=12Za1i1zhYTCeHWBg8yJb72BeEGQVEuMdT&callback=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

This works.

Comment: How can you have cross-domain issues in server-side PHP?

Comment: I suspect that @GoriFater does not have `https` enabled and switching to `http` fixed the issue, but not for any cross-domain issue.

Comment: No, I don't have it enabled; you are right on that. ¡Gracias por la ayuda! :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php configuration?

if not you will get a warning generated  - do you have errors/warnings displayed?

to check errors add below lines at top of the script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

and then you might see why `file_get_contents()` doesn't work.